# Opening SqlConnection inside TransactionScope error

Tags: azure, ado.net, transactionscope, sqlconnection

We have been trying to use a `SqlConnection` within a `TransactionScope`. When we build the site and try this database call we run into an error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

The error involved occurs on the line `cnn.Open()`.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    int result = cnn.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT 1");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

We created a console application to figure out what was wrong and discovered that by changing our connection string keyword 'Pooling' from 'false' to 'true' allows this to run in the console application and successfully return our result.

We made the same change to our site connection string, the same error as before returns.

Is there any reason this code is not working?

Comment: First, why is pooling off? Secondly, this smells like the pooling causing the same physical connection to be reused for multiple logical connections. This is non-deterministic and can break at any time. Post more complete code. Likely, there are multiple queries or multiple Open's.

Comment: Pooling was off in the connection string given to us by the Azure Portal. We tried turning this on and it worked on my local machine, but not when deployed to our web app. It makes no difference when there is one or multiple queries or connections, it fails on the very first Open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the assumption that the web.config was law, as viewing the file through the Kudu service showed my expected connection string, but apparently this isn't the case in Azure.

I discovered that Azure Publish Profile is overriding our web.config connection string, this override still contained 'Pooling=false'.

Removing this now allows our code to run as intended.

[This blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) explains more:

> "When this code runs on a developer’s local machine, the value returned will be the one from the web.config file.  However when this code runs in Windows Azure Web Sites, the value returned will instead be overridden with the value entered in the portal"